# How DOM and Javascript interacts?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am a begineer in Javascript. I learnt to use document object and manipulate DOM. Now i am curiuos to now some insights of document and javascript objects, 
Explaining below my question...

As i am getting Javascript and document object provided by browser are two different things and their is interaction between two parties one is browser and second is javascript which will manipulate DOM. **Now my question is How document is providing all its entities into Javascript understandable objects.**
**Eg: var obj = document.getElementById('id1');**
 point1 : **var obj is an javascript object.**
 point2 : **document.getElementById('id1'); returns javascript object .**
 Yes it happens that DOM provides javascript obects. 
**Being two different entities Is their any contract between them for communication ?**

Comment: The "contract" (strange term) for communication is called DOM API.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) mozilla documentation would be a great place to start

Comment: thanks you @connexo ...